# как обновить список после передачи фото из onActivityResult в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Данные в массив заносятся, а список не обновляется

Adapter

```
class AdapterImages: ListAdapter<ImageModel, AdapterImages.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    class ViewHolder(
        val item: ItemImageBinding
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item.root) {

        fun bind(uri: ImageModel) {
            item.image.setImageURI(uri.uri)
        }
    }

    private class DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ImageModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ImageModel, newItem: ImageModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem.uri == newItem.uri
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ImageModel, newItem: ImageModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ViewHolder(
        ItemImageBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.context
            )
        )
    )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(currentList[position])
    }

    fun addImage(uri: ImageModel) {
        //val callback = DiffUtil.Callback
        submitList(listOf(uri))
        Log.d("AddImageRV", "Добавление картинки в список")
    }

}
```

Activity

```
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            adapter.addImage(uri = ImageModel(data?.data!!))
        }
    }
```

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Что значит "список не обновляется"? Разве картинка не меняется:)? Вы каждый раз создаёте новый список с одним элементом и этим списком заменяете предыдущий. Вам нужно либо хранить в адаптере список всех элементов, в него добавлять новые и им обновлять адаптер. Либо получить текущий список `currentList`, сделать его копию, добавить новый элемент и вернуть копию адаптеру в `submitList()`. Вообще `ListAdapter` целесообразно использовать при частых обновлениях базы, данных из сети и т.п. - подписался и забыл. А при добавлении по одному элементу - простого `RecyclerView.Adapter` хватит за глаза.

Comment: @Style-7 нотифай есть

Comment: @woesss картинка и не появляется, если в обычное ImageView передавать то всё работает

Comment: А зачем вы пишите что не обновляется, если он изначально не отображается... Тогда у вас проблема или в разметке, или в настройке `RecyclerView` (но это не точно;)